# Screen lock error during upgrade to 22.04 from 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, authentication

yesterday, I've tried to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04, accidentally I closed the laptop which I guess locked the screen. Now when I try to unlock it, I get an "Authentication Error" and I can't enter my password. Does anyone have a suggestion on what to do, I did my research but there is not much said about this I guess.

Thanks

Comment: After interrupting an upgrade the next step is reinstall.

Comment: @David I strongly disagree, as per my answer. It's very possible and not hard to recover a system which had an interrupted upgrade. I've done it plenty of times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can logon from a tty/console (CTRL+ALT+F3 through F6). From there you can check the `/var/log/dpkg.log`. If it's still processing, perhaps leave it.

If you ran the upgrade using the graphical "Update Manager" then you may see it busy in "top" on the terminal. If you used `do-release-upgrade` then you may see that.

If you did use `do-release-upgrade`, then you may be able to "attach" to is with the `screen -r` to reconnect to it. However that's not possible if you used "Update Manager".

Alternatively kill the upgrade that's running and then immediately `dpkg --configure -a` which will finish off whatever apt package upgrades were in flight. This is usually sufficient to complete the upgrade, by carrying on where it left off when you suspended it.

If you do choose this path, make sure you kill the right things. Don’t reboot again until you get past killing the processes and re-running `dpkg`.

Find the update-manager process:

`ps aux | grep update-manager | grep -v grep`

If there’s a line of output like this:

`alan     3269811  0.0  0.0   9076  2200 pts/2    S+   21:33   0:00 /usr/bin/update-manager`

Take the number from the second column (in my case 3269811, yours will differ), and use it to kill the process:

`sudo kill -9 3269811`

I’d also check for any `dpkg` processes using:

`ps aux | grep dpkg | grep -v grep`

Again, if there is one running, we can kill it with the same process as above.

Now try and finish off the package upgrades with:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

In theory, you will likely see some packages whizz by as they’re updated.

If that works (as in, runs to completion), then you may want to just do one last `sudo apt update ; sudo apt full-upgrade` or `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` in case anything went missing in the meantime. Then reboot and cross your fingers ;)

Comment: A lot of if, maybe and it might work as well as cross your fingers in this answer. For the average user a new install would most likely be the right answer.

Comment: @popey thanks a lot mate for the detailed answer. I need to go through with this and try it, i have one question though, how can i kill the upgrade from CTRL+ALT+F2 terminal? Im upgrading using update manager.

Comment: I'll update the answer with some more detail...

Comment: @popey oh man that was epic, everything worked as you described, this is the lsb_release:

~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

thank you very very much, you saved my a** :)

one quick note: I had to kill the processes from tty3, tty2 was stuck for some reason, but other than that, it worked flawlessly.

thanks a lot popey :-)

Comment: Happy days! Glad it worked @Algor